# onChange of <select> element in child component not re-rendering the parent state in React, Warning: unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm lifting state up from child to parent and trying to render select elements with data from HTTP request. The select tag values within the `Inv` child component will show previously selected values, but I'm getting this error:

> Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak
>   in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous
>   tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

It looks like the error is coming from the `Inv` child component that is being passed props with `this.state.identInvsData`. That is the only time I get the error. The child components in the else statements that don't get the `identInvsData` don't get that error message. The parent component does not re-render, or "mount" the children.
Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

> Edit: The child components are populating the data from HTTP endpoint, but onChange it
>   doesn't change the values in `setState`, only when I select the button `Add Inv`. It adds another child but also allows the previous children to change.

Identity Parent Component

```
class Identity extends React.Component {  

      state = {
        invIds: [],
        inTypes: [],
        invSeqIds: [],
        numChildren: 0,
        addInvBtnPressed: false
      };

      handleAddInv = () => {
        this.setState({
          numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1,
          addInvBtnPressed: true
        });
      };

      onChangeInv = (e, index, sId) => {
        const invIdsArry = this.state.invIds;
        const invSeqIdsArry = this.state.invSeqIds;
        const newId = [
          ...invIdsArry.slice(0, index),
          (invIdsArry[index] = e.target.value),
          ...invIdsArry.slice(index + 1)
        ];
        if (sId) {
          const newSeqId = [
            ...invSeqIdsArry.slice(0, index),
            (invSeqIdsArry[index] = sId),
            ...invSeqIdsArry.slice(index + 1)
          ];
          this.setState({ invIds: newId, invSeqIds: newSeqId });
        } else {
          this.setState({ invIds: newId });
        }
      };

      onChangeType = (e, index) => {
        const invTypesArry = this.state.invTypes;
        const newTypes = [
          ...invTypesArry.slice(0, index),
          (invTypesArry[index] = e.target.value),
          ...invTypesArry.slice(index + 1)
        ];
        this.setState({ invTypes: newTypes });
      };


      render() {
        const children = [];
        var i;
        if (this.state.identInvsData && !this.state.addInvBtnPressed) {
          for (i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
            children.push(
              <Inv
                key={i}
                invKey={i}
                onChangeInv={this.onChangeInv.bind(this)}
                onChangeType={this.onChangeType.bind(this)}
                invId={this.state.identInvsData[i].invId}
                invType={this.state.identInvsData[i].invTypeCd}
                seqId={this.state.identInvsData[i].seqId}
                invData={this.state.identInvsData[i]}
              />
            );
          }
        } else if (this.state.identInvsData && this.state.addInvBtnPressed) {
          for (i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
            children.push(
              <Inv
                key={i}
                invKey={i}
                onChangeInv={this.onChangeInv.bind(this)}
                onChangeType={this.onChangeType.bind(this)}
              />
            );
          }
        } else {
          for (i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
            children.push(
              <Inv
                key={i}
                invKey={i}
                onChangeInv={this.onChangeInv.bind(this)}
                onChangeType={this.onChangeType.bind(this)}
              />
            );
          }
        }
        return (
          <div>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-info"
              onClick={this.handleAddInv}
            >
              Add Inv
            </button>
            <div>{children}</div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Identity;
```

Inv Child Component

```
class Inv extends React.Component {

    state = {
      kddLookupData: "",
      invData: ""
    };

    componentDidMount = () => {
      kddlookups_getAll().then(resp => {
        this.setState({
          kddLookupData: resp.data.item
        });
      });
      invs_getAll().then(resp => {
        this.setState({
          invData: resp.data.items
        });
      });
    };

    handleInvestigatorChange = e => {
      this.props.onChangeInv(e, this.props.invKey, this.props.seqId);
    };

    handleInvestigatorTypeChange = e => {
      this.props.onChangeType(e, this.props.invKey);
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <select
            value={this.props.invId}
            name={this.props.invKey}
            onChange={this.handleInvChange.bind(this)}
          >
            <option className="blank">Select inv name:</option>
            {this.state.invData &&
             this.state.invData.map(inv => {
                return (
                   <option key={inv.userId} value={inv.userId}>
                      {inv.invName}
                   </option>
                );
              })}
          </select>

          <select
            value={this.props.invType}
            name={this.props.invKey}
            onChange={this.handleInvTypeChange.bind(this)}
          >
            <option className="blank">Select inv type:</option>
            {this.state.kddData &&
             this.state.kddData.kdd_inv_type.map(inv => {
               return (
                  <option key={inv.inv_type_cd} value={inv.inv_type_cd}>
                     {inv.inv_type_name}
                  </option>
               );
             })}
          </select>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Inv;
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are returning anything in your render function in the child component. Try:

```
render() {
return (
   <div>
      <select
        value={this.props.invId}
        name={this.props.invKey}
        onChange={this.handleInvChange.bind(this)}
      >
        <option className="blank">Select inv name:</option>
        {this.state.invData &&
         this.state.invData.map(inv => {
            return (
               <option key={inv.userId} value={inv.userId}>
                  {inv.invName}
               </option>
            );
          })}
      </select>

      <select
        value={this.props.invType}
        name={this.props.invKey}
        onChange={this.handleInvTypeChange.bind(this)}
      >
        <option className="blank">Select inv type:</option>
        {this.state.kddData &&
         this.state.kddData.kdd_inv_type.map(inv => {
           return (
              <option key={inv.inv_type_cd} value={inv.inv_type_cd}>
                 {inv.inv_type_name}
              </option>
           );
         })}
      </select>
      </div>
   );
 }
```

Comment: I made a change to my post, I forgot to mention some important details. I also did forget to add the return in my post. I already have the return in my child's code.

Comment: Did you mean to access invData from the props instead of the state in the child component?

Comment: I am so bad at this, still getting use to asking proper questions. I just added my correct code to the post. The `invData` is actually coming from within the child component within it's own state to populate a dropdown of values in the select element.

Comment: Ok so your child component is only updating the state when the component mounts? Maybe take a closer look at the props you are passing in. If those props aren't changing, then your child will not update. If you aren't calling setState anywhere either (other than on component mount) then the component will not rerender until it is mounted again

Comment: No, the child component doesn't update the parent state when the parent state mounts. The child has a dropdown of values which are populated, but when I try to change it I see the values of dropdown and click on one but it doesn't change the state of the parent component. It only changes once I click the "Add Inv" button, and that's what allows me access to setting the state somehow.